# Haskell - Pattern Synonyms, View Patterns, GADTs

Tags: haskell

I'm now trying out 2 pieces of code from:

https://mpickering.github.io/posts/2015-12-12-pattern-synonyms-8.html

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
```

In the first piece of code:

```
pattern IsTrue :: Show a => a
pattern IsTrue <- ((== "True") . show -> True)
test10 = IsTrue "True"
```

The following error was thrown:

```
• non-bidirectional pattern synonym ‘IsTrue’ used in an expression
• In the expression: IsTrue "True"
```

In the second piece of code:

```
data T where
  MkT :: (Show b) => b -> T
pattern ExNumPat :: () => Show b => b -> T
pattern ExNumPat x = MkT x
test11 = ExNumPat True
```

The following error was thrown when I run `test11`:

```
• No instance for (Show T) arising from a use of ‘print’
```

What caused these 2 errors and how do I resolve them?  And how do the patterns work?

Comment: Your `IsTrue` pattern can only be used as *pattern*, not as an expression, since view patterns are non-bidirectional as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Thanks, so how do I use the pattern?

Comment: https://rextester.com/FQWJ64695

Comment: @maxloo: `f IsTrue = 1` for example, then if you write `f True` for example, it will return `1`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Thanks, but what does the syntax mean?  `<-` tells GHC to replace the term on its left with the term on its right, but why is there an equivalence to a string `"True"`?  And why is it composed with `show -> True`?  `pattern IsTrue <- ((== "True") . show -> True)`

Comment: That is what the view pattern does: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/view-patterns

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks, how about my second piece of code?

Comment: You don't have a `Show` instance for `T`.  Try adding `deriving instance Show T` to your file (note that this will necessitate adding `{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}` as well).

Answer (score 1):

## First error

Problem 1: Since your pattern synonym uses `<-` and not `=`, and it doesn't have a `where`, it's unidirectional, so you can only match on it, not use it as a value. You can make it explicitly bidirectional by doing something like this:

```
pattern IsTrue :: (Read a, Show a) => a
pattern IsTrue <- ((== "True") . show -> True)
  where IsTrue = read "True"
```

Although for that particular pattern, that's really contrived and probably never actually useful.

Problem 2: Functions don't have `Show` instances, and in `IsTrue "True"`, you're trying to use `IsTrue` as a function even though it requires a `Show` instance.

## Second error

Your code only ensures that the `b` in `MkT` has a `Show` instance, but you're trying to `show` the whole `T`, which does not have a `Show` instance. Either pattern-match the `b` back out of it and just `show` that, or add a `Show` instance to `t`.

Comment: Thanks, how should I pattern match the `b` back out of it and just `show` that?  I tried `testExNumPat :: (forall b. Show b => b -> T)`; `testExNumPat (ExNumPat (1::Int)) = MkT 1`; `test12 = testExNumPat (ExNumPat 1)`, but got an error: `Couldn't match expected type ‘b1’ with actual type ‘Int’`; `‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by a pattern with pattern synonym: ExNumPat :: () => forall b. Show b => b -> T`.  This was done with `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: @maxloo new question? new post please.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard, ok, I've posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285976/haskell-pattern-synonyms-gadt-pattern-matching.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, could you provide a clarification please about your answer?  "add a Show instance to T" works, but I do not know how to "pattern-match the b back out of it and just show that".  I believe there are many learners out there who will be keen on knowing this answer.