# Haskell - Pattern Synonyms, GADT, pattern matching

Tags: haskell

Based on the answer for the second problem I face at:

[Haskell - Pattern Synonyms, View Patterns, GADTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245095/haskell-pattern-synonyms-view-patterns-gadts)

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data T where
  MkT :: (Show b) => b -> T
pattern ExNumPat :: () => Show b => b -> T
pattern ExNumPat x = MkT x
test11 = ExNumPat "True"
```

The answerer says "pattern-match the `b` back out of it and just `show` that" as one of the ways to resolve my error.  Could it be further explained?  How do I do that?  I've tried adding the following, besides other variations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
testExNumPat :: (forall b. Show b => (b -> T) -> T)
testExNumPat (ExNumPat (1::Int)) = MkT 1
test12 = testExNumPat (ExNumPat 1)
```

But I always ended up with many more errors.  For this
particular case, the errors are:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘b -> T’ with actual type ‘T’
• In the pattern: ExNumPat (1 :: Int)

• Couldn't match expected type ‘b3’ with actual type ‘Int’
  ‘b3’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with pattern synonym:
      ExNumPat :: () => forall b. Show b => b -> T

• Couldn't match expected type ‘b1 -> T’ with actual type ‘T’
• Possible cause: ‘ExNumPat’ is applied to too many arguments
```

Comment: I think it is better to ask for clarification of that answer instead of asking a second question like this. Or alternatively make this a self-contained question by adding more of the context from your other question to this question.

Comment: @Noughtmare, thanks, I've added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues here: as the error message says, your type for `testExNumPat` is wrong, I think it should be `testExNumPat :: T -> T`; and secondly you match on an `Int` in the `ExNumPat`, but the contained value is existentially quantified, so you can't know that this value will always be an `Int`. To show the contained value you can simply call show on it:

```
testExNumPat :: T -> String
testExNumPat (ExNumPat x) = show x

test12 = testExNumPat (ExNumPat 1)
```